# lodash find object inside object

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

i am trying to return true if object exists with

```
var primary={
  "RHID": {
    "type": "numeric"
  },
  "CD_DOC_ID": {
    "type": "numeric"
  },
  "SEQ": {
    "type": "numeric"
  }
}

console.log(_.contains(primary, 'RHID'))
```

But aways get false. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`_.has` method](https://lodash.com/docs#has)

```
console.log(_.has(primary, 'RHID'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`RHID` is a key inside the object `primary`, so you should look up in the keys of `primary`.

loDash function `_.keys` returns an array of all the object keys, yo ucan use it this way:

```
console.log(_.contains(_.keys(primary), 'RHID')) // true
```

Comment: You're welcome. @suvroc provided a more straightforward solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

A `lodash` solution using [has()](https://lodash.com/docs#has) or [hasIn()](https://lodash.com/docs#hasIn):

```
var primary=
{
    "RHID": {
      "type": "numeric"
    },
    "CD_DOC_ID": {
      "type": "numeric"
    },
    "SEQ": {
      "type": "numeric"
    }
}
console.log(_.has(primary, 'RHID'));
```

`_.has()` checks for own properties, `_.hasIn()` verifies for own and inherited ones.

But it would be better to use `in` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
var primary=
{
    "RHID": {
      "type": "numeric"
    },
    "CD_DOC_ID": {
      "type": "numeric"
    },
    "SEQ": {
      "type": "numeric"
    }
}

console.log('RHID' in primary);
```

Comment: In is a really nice solution: Have never used it thanks!

Comment: @chriskelly `in` is from ES3 actually

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos Using lodash it would be easier `_.get(primary, 'RHID.type', null) === "numeric"`